# jQuery slidetoggle function breaks when additional div is added

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-ui-accordion

The function below acts as an slidetoggle accordion (for a list of Wordpress posts) and it does a number of things, like toggle, add active classes and "declick" the open toggle div. Worked fine with the three divs - .entry-post, .entry-title and .entry-content - until... wait for it... I needed to add another div in the markup.

The other div I needed to add is for the publication date, and with that fourth div, the accordion action breaks, because the function operates in determining the next div.

How can I get this function to take into account and ignore thedate div I had to add in the markup? (I can't change the div to a span.)

**JSfiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/WnpGv/53/

**Function:**

```
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $content = $this.next(".entry-content");
    if (! $this.is('.active-title')) {
        $('.active-title').removeClass('active-title');
        $this.addClass('active-title');
        $(".entry-content:visible").slideToggle(400);
        $content.slideToggle(400);
    }
});
```

**Basic markup:**

```
<div class="entry-post">

    <h2 class="entry-title">Post Title 1</h2>

    <div class="thedate">(publication date)</div> <!--this is the div I added -->

<div class="entry-content">Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change `next()`, it *always* looks at the next sibling element:

> (`next()` gets) the **immediately following sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements. **If a selector is provided**, it retrieves the next sibling **only if** it matches that selector.

[emphasis mine.]

You could, however, use `parent()` and `find()`:

```
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $content = $this.parent('.entry-post').find(".entry-content");
    if (!$this.is('.active-title')) {
        $('.active-title').removeClass('active-title');
        $this.addClass('active-title');
        $(".entry-content:visible").slideToggle(400);
        $content.slideToggle(400);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnpGv/54/).

---

**Edited** to use `closest('.entry-post')` in place of `parent('.entry-post')`:

```
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $content = $this.parent('.entry-post').find(".entry-content");
    if (!$this.is('.active-title')) {
        $('.active-title').removeClass('active-title');
        $this.addClass('active-title');
        $(".entry-content:visible").slideToggle(400);
        $content.slideToggle(400);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnpGv/55/).

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Ah, that works great. Esp. the second one, as I forgot I use the same function for different markup in the same site - markup that doesn't have the extra thedate div - and by using closest instead of parent, that one continues to work. Still learning this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @songdogtech: glad to have been of help! :)